# How to do 1000 permutations of column names with test statistics distribution?

Tags: r, permutation

let's say I have a matrix like this

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   code.1 code.2 code.3 code.4
1     82     93     NA     NA
2     15     85     93     NA
3     93     89     NA     NA
4     81     NA     NA     NA",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat2=data.matrix(dat)
```

In reality my matrix has 132 columns and around 15000 rows.
And my column names look like this: NoD_14569_norm.1 NoD_14569_norm.2 NoD_14569_norm.3 NoD_14581_30mM.1 NoD_14581_30mM.2 NoD_14581_30mM.3

What I want to do is create a 1000 random permutations of my column names where everything in the matrix would stay the same except there would be new order of column names.

for example one permutation/reshuffling of column names would give me this:

```
  code.2 code.4 code.1 code.3
1     82     93     NA     NA
2     15     85     93     NA
3     93     89     NA     NA
4     81     NA     NA     NA
```

The goal is to perform the following code on each of 1000 data frames

```
subject="all_replicate"
targets<-readTargets(paste(PhenotypeDir,"hg_sg_",subject,"_target.txt", sep=''))
Treat <- factor(targets$Treatment,levels=c("C","T"))
Replicates <- factor(targets$rep)
design <- model.matrix(~Replicates+Treat)
corfit <- duplicateCorrelation(dat2, block = targets$Subject)
corfit$consensus.correlation
fit <-lmFit(dat2,design,block=targets$Subject,correlation=corfit$consensus.correlation)
fit<-eBayes(fit)
y1=topTable(fit, coef="TreatT", n=nrow(genes),adjust.method="BH",genelist=genes)
```

Inside of y1 there is column names P.value containing p values and I would like to plot distribution of those for all above mentioned 1000 permutations of column names.

Please advise

Comment: By *"new order of column names"*, do you mean `dat2[,sample(ncol(dat2))]`? Or do you mean `colnames(dat2) <- sample(colnames(dat2))`?

Comment: thanks for the input, I updated my question to reflect what I mean exactly

Comment: I should probably not call it permutation but just reshuffling of column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random ordering of column names is easy enough:

```r
set.seed(42)
# manyorders <- replicate(1000, sample(colnames(dat2)), simplify=FALSE)
# set.seed(42)
manyorders <- replicate(1000, sample(colnames(dat2)), simplify=FALSE)
head(manyorders)
# [[1]]
# [1] "code.4" "code.3" "code.1" "code.2"
# [[2]]
# [1] "code.3" "code.2" "code.4" "code.1"
# [[3]]
# [1] "code.3" "code.4" "code.1" "code.2"
# [[4]]
# [1] "code.4" "code.1" "code.3" "code.2"
# [[5]]
# [1] "code.4" "code.1" "code.3" "code.2"
# [[6]]
# [1] "code.4" "code.1" "code.2" "code.3"
```

From here, you can do one of:

```r
### 1, rename-in-copy
for (ord in manyorders) {
  tmpdat <- `colnames<-`(dat2, ord) # copies and renames in one line ... code-golf
  # ... your code
}

### 2, rename in place
for (ord in manyorders) {
  colnames(dat2) <- ord
  # ... your code
}

### 3, lapply, effectively rename-in-copy
all_results <- lapply(manyorders, function(ord) {
  tmpdat <- `colnames<-`(dat2, ord) # copies and renames in one line ... code-golf
  # ... your code, ending in ...
  fit <- eBayes(fit)
  y1 <- topTable(fit, coef="TreatT", n=nrow(genes), adjust.method="BH", genelist=genes)
  list(fit = fit, y1 = y1)
})
```

This last one allows you to look at the `fit` and `y1` components for any run, generating this in an efficient manner.

Comment: Hi I was running this 3rd version you offered with 100 permutations and I wrote all_results in a file. But later when I tried to open that file in R > a=read.table("all_res", header=T)
Error in read.table("all_res", header = T) : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: How did you write `all_results` to a file? What does it look like? I did not expect it to look like a `data.frame`, so I would not expect it to be easily readable with `read.table`. (This is a different issue, though, so it's probably better to open a new question with `dput(all_results[1:2])` and how you saved to a file.)

Comment: Thanks! this is how I save it: write.table(all_results, file="all_res", sep = " ", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE,quote=FALSE)

Comment: If you want to save the results and reuse them later, I suggest using `save` or `saveRDS`, as they will preserve the structure and attributes you likely need. Otherwise, please open a new question, this is different from your current question here.